# How to log queries that go to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Tags: wordpress

I need a way to log queries that go to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php (extra points if I can log specific queries). This will help to troubleshoot some stuff happening in production with my custom plugin.

**Scenario**
I’ve been working on a plugin which varies the message a user gets depending on the time on the server. The process also depends on other settings retrieved from the server.
The plugin uses javascript to call admin-ajax.php to do the magic. (due to the nature of the plugin, I don’t think I can or should use straight client-side JS for this).
In development it works reliably but in production there are definitely situations where the result returned is unexpected.
This has led me to think that the results of admin-ajax.php are sometimes cached, I need a way to validate my current guess by doing some logging of responses from the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in you theme functions.php

A log file ajaxlog.txt will now be created in your template folder

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_ajax_checker', 10, 2);

function my_ajax_checker() {
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/ajaxlog.txt';
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$message = $actual_link . " - " . date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()) . " - " .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\r\n" ;
file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
}
}
```

Send requests with a unique identifier and then count if they are all in the log.